# How to pass params into method call from within vue js template?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

So inside my template I have the following:

```
          <template v-for="item in jobs">
            <tr>
                <td v-for="stage in item.stage_execs" :style="getStyle(stage.status.name)" :title="stage.exec_node.name" >
                  <b><a :href="[[ item.mongo_link ]]/[[stage.name]]">[[ stage.name ]]</a></b>
                  <br>
                  [[ stage.duration_millis | durationReadable  ]]
                  <br>
                  [[ stage.status.name ]]
                </td>
            </tr>
          </template>
```

The problem is I am trying to create a href link with two variables, but I don't think I can do that in vue.js

I'm hoping there IS a way to do this and I just don't know about it, otherwise I can just write a method to create the link and call it like:

```
<a :href="[[ generateMongoLink ]]">
```

The question I have (if I have to go this route) is how do I pass two params into the method from this call above?  I want to call with item.mongo_link and stage.name

Comment: `:href="item.mongo_link + '/' + stage.name"`

Comment: wow it was that easy., thanks

Comment: or ``:href="`${item.mongo_link}/${stage.name}`"``

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change:

```
<a :href="[[ item.mongo_link ]]/[[stage.name]]">
```

to

```
<a :href="`${item.mongo_link}/${stage.name}`">
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit cleaner way is using methods

```
methods: {
    generateMongoLink(item) {
     return item.mongo_link + '/' + stage.name"
   }
 }
```

Then in template

```
<a :href="generateMongoLink(item)">
```